# Como exibir imagens no ListView vindas do Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Bom eu estou recebendo inúmeras informações do firebase, e as exibindo, porem gostaria de receber também imagens, sem ultizar o storege, eu ja salvei algumas urls no banco de dados e quando eu puxasse a url ele montaria a imagem direto no app. Como posso fazer isso ???

### O meu adapter

```
public class NoticiaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Noticias> {
private ArrayList<Noticias> noticias;
private Context context;
public NoticiaAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Noticias> objects) {
    super(c, 0, objects);
    this.noticias = objects;
    this.context = c;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    //Criamos o objeto do tipo view
    View v = null;
    //Vemos se esta vazio
    if(noticias != null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Recupera o XML da lista
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_noticias,parent, false);
        TextView tituloNoticia = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_lista_noticias);
        TextView dataNoticia = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_lista_data);
        Noticias noticia = noticias.get(position);
        tituloNoticia.setText(noticia.getTitulo());
        dataNoticia.setText(noticia.getData());
    }
    return  v;
 }
}
```

### Classe modelo

```
public class Noticias {
private String titulo;
private String noticia;
private String data;
private String imagem;

public Noticias() {
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getNoticia() {
    return noticia;
}

public void setNoticia(String noticia) {
    this.noticia = noticia;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getImagem() {
    return imagem;
}

public void setImagem(String imagem) {
    this.imagem = imagem;
 }
}
```

### O fragment que recebe os dados

```
public class fragmentNoticias extends Fragment {
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Noticias> noticias;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

public fragmentNoticias() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    /*Chamamos o metodo do event listener aqui para otimizarmos os dados
     quando o fragment for gerado*/
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Da mesma maneira removemos a chamada do Firebase quando o fragmente for eliminado
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noticias, container, false);
    //Intanciando o Array de noticias
    noticias = new ArrayList<>();
    //Instanciando o listView recuperado do layout
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_noticias);
    //Instanciando o Adapter
    /*adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
     // O getActivity recupera para o fragment o parametro Activity da classe pai (MainActivity)
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            noticias
    );*/
    adapter = new NoticiaAdapter(getActivity(), noticias);

    //Setando o adpter no ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Chamando o autentication
    autenticacao = FirebaseConfig.getAutenticacao();
    //Chamando a referencia do firebase para poder ter acesso ao BD
    databaseReference = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Noticias").child("TabelaNoticias");
    /*Aqui nos chamamos a função onde iremos listar os dados, colocamos ela dentro de uma
    de uma variavel pra poder otimizar o uso e só chamar essa função quando o fragmente for criado
    e eliminala quando o fragmente for eliminado*/
    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //O clear vai limpar a lista para não chamar os dados mais de uma vez
            noticias.clear();
            //Aqui temos o for onde o laço vai pegar todas as noticias
            for(DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                /*Chamamos a classe modelo Noticias pra poder gravarmos os dados vindos do firebase
                em um obj */
                Noticias noticia = dados.getValue(Noticias.class);
                //pegamos só o titulo da noticia
                noticias.add(noticia);
            }
            //Passamos os dados do fireBase para o adapter poder popular o Listview
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NoticiaActivity.class);

            Noticias noti = noticias.get(position);

            i.putExtra("noticia",noti.getNoticia());
            i.putExtra("titulo",noti.getTitulo());
            i.putExtra("data",noti.getData());

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return view;
 }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já consegue ver a url dentro do app?

Comment: sim, eu consigo puxar a url em formato de texto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem mais de uma possibilidade de realizar esse procedimento. Vou mostrar 2 formas usando *framework* e uma "na raça". Acompanhe abaixo:

#### 1. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

O Picasso é um  *framework* que permite o carregamento de imagens sem complicações. Veja como deve ser feito:

**Gradle**:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

**Como usar**:

Ai no seu código basta fazer desta forma abaixo, passando como parâmetro do método `into()` seu `ImageView`. Veja:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

#### 2. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

O Glide possui o mesmo propósito de carregamento de imagem, com foco no cache e na suavidade em relação ao *scroll*.

**Gradle**:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

**Como usar**:

Também muito parecido com o Picasso, no código basta fazer desta forma abaixo, passando também como parâmetro do método `into()` seu `ImageView`. Veja:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
Glide.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

> **Obs.:** Verifique a versão mais atual de release no site do *framework*

Caso não queria usar nenhum desses *framework*, você pode fazer "na raça" usando o `InputStream` através de um `AsyncTask`. É importante você ler um pouco sobre as vantagens de usar um desses *framework* para o propósito, pois pode facilitar na questão do tratamento da image, por exemplo *cache* e *crop* de imagens. Veja como deve ficar:

```
// Aqui mostra a imagem no ImageView
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView))
            .execute("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png");

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Fonte: [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)